# Repeater binding with stored procedure in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, repeater

I have a stored procedure `SP1` which is returning the result set as

```
select column1 [Col(1)] from table1
```

My repeater in the ASPX page is this here:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <%# Eval("Col(1)")%>                                    
         </td>                                
      </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>                        
</asp:Repeater>
```

But, calling `<%# Eval("Col(1)") %>`, I am getting an error:

> "DataBinding: 'System.String' does not allow indexed access"

Reason is very clear that `Col(1)` is the pain. Since I can't change the stored procedure, so how can I handle this situation in asp.net?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[]` indexer of DataItem. Index value 0 for the first item (column) and so on.

```
<%# Eval("[0]") %>
```

Or

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[0]")%>
```

Comment: So, is there no way to mention the returned column name of stored procedure?

Comment: @Zohaib - Posted code will do exactly as your need. If col(1) contains "something" then it prints "something".

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column_Name") %>
        </td>   
       </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>                        
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Directly mention the the Column name used in stored procedure.

**Edited after Comment**

Try this then

```
<%# eval("Column_Name") %>
```

Comment: I tried like you mentioned <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col(1)") %>, but still same problem.

Comment: hmm...try this then <%# eval("Column Name") %>